# How to Disable Autoscrolling in richtextbox in c#

Tags: c#, scroll, richtextbox

i want to disable the scrolling feature of richtextbox in c#. i just want to make richtextbox to allow user to enter only in its size area, means no vertical scrolling for user. just like  MS-word or open Office Pages.thanx in advance.

Comment: Do you use WPF? Or WinForms? Or...?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/068b31bd-c659-4b21-a02a-46bf9b9f39f2/richtextbox-controlling-scrolling-when-appending-text

Answer (score 1):

You should override [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and block [WM_SETFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if(m.Msg != WM_SETFOCUS)
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Here is a tutorial about this : [How to: C# - Prevent RichTextBox from auto scrolling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361161/How-to-Csharp-Prevent-RichTextBox-from-auto-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

First thing as you may have seen in other posts you need access to **user32.dll** from C#.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);


    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwndLock,Int32 wMsg,Int32 wParam, ref Point pt);
```

We need to make some constant declaration to make the **SendMessage** calls properly.

```
private const int WM_USER = 0x400;
private const int EM_HIDESELECTION = WM_USER + 63;
private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0x000B;
private const int EM_GETSCROLLPOS = WM_USER + 221;
private const int EM_SETSCROLLPOS = WM_USER + 222;
```

Then, some public static methods to be used whenever we need to stop scrolling.

```
    public static void Suspend(Control control)
    {
        Message msgSuspendUpdate = Message.Create(control.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        NativeWindow window = NativeWindow.FromHandle(control.Handle);
        window.DefWndProc(ref msgSuspendUpdate);
    }

    public static void Resume(Control control)
    {
        // Create a C "true" boolean as an IntPtr
        IntPtr wparam = new IntPtr(1);
        Message msgResumeUpdate = Message.Create(control.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, wparam,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        NativeWindow window = NativeWindow.FromHandle(control.Handle);
        window.DefWndProc(ref msgResumeUpdate);

        control.Invalidate();
    }


    public static Point GetScrollPoint(Control control) {
        Point point = new Point();
        SendMessage(control.Handle, EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref point);
        return point;
    }

    public static void SetScrollPoint(Control control, Point point)
    {
        SendMessage(control.Handle, EM_SETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref point);

    }
```

The **Suspend** method stops the **Control** to make a redraw on the screen. The **Resume** method restarts redraws on the screen for the given **Control**.

The **GetScrollPoint** method gets the actual **Point** where the scroll caret is located. The **SetScrollPoint** puts the scroll caret at the given **point**.

How to use these methods? First, given a **Control** you need to stop autoscroll, make the call to **Suspend**, then to **GetScrollPoint**, (make what you need to do with the control, like highlight or append text) then **SetScrollPoint** and finally **Resume**.

In my case, I wanted to copy the entire line of a **RichTextBox** at any time when the cursor moves from line to line. (Doing so produce a scroll on long lines).

This is my working method:

```
    private int intLastLine = -1;
    private void richTextBoxSwitch_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.richTextBoxSwitch.TextLength > 0)
            {
                ControlBehavior.Suspend(this.richTextBoxSwitch);
                Point point = ControlBehavior.GetScrollPoint(this.richTextBoxSwitch);
                int intSelectionStartBackup = this.richTextBoxSwitch.SelectionStart;
                int intSelectionLengthBackup = this.richTextBoxSwitch.SelectionLength;

                int intCharIndex = this.richTextBoxSwitch.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
                int intLine = this.richTextBoxSwitch.GetLineFromCharIndex(intCharIndex);

                this.richTextBoxSwitch.SuspendLayout();
                if (intLastLine != intLine)
                {
                    intLastLine = intLine;
                    int intLength = this.richTextBoxSwitch.Lines[intLine].Length;
                    this.richTextBoxSwitch.Select(intCharIndex, intLength);
                    this.richTextBoxSwitch.BackColor = ColorMessageBackground;
                    strData = this.richTextBoxSwitch.SelectedText;
                    this.textBoxMessageSelected.Text = strData.Trim();
                    this.richTextBoxSwitch.Select(intSelectionStartBackup, intSelectionLengthBackup);
                }
                this.richTextBoxSwitch.ResumeLayout();
                ControlBehavior.SetScrollPoint(this.richTextBoxSwitch, point);
                ControlBehavior.Resume(this.richTextBoxSwitch);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!